# Can I find a button by it's html in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I need to find the 'Today' button in jQuery UI Datepicker and remove it.

This is it's html:

```
<button onclick="DP_jQuery_1295079747879.datepicker._gotoToday('#newMessageExpirationDate');" class="ui-datepicker-current ui-state-default ui-priority-secondary ui-corner-all" type="button">Today</button>
```

I tried this

```
buttonPanel.find('button[innerHtml="Today"]')
buttonPanel.find('button[html="Today"]')
buttonPanel.find('button[value="Today"]')
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector):

```
buttonPanel.find('button:contains("Today")')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [:contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

```
buttonPanel.find('button:contains("Today")')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, the [] syntax is for attribute matching. Why can't you match by id or class instead?

Comment: It seems it doesn't have an id, and the classes aren't unique, the other buttons have them too.